# Adding an offset to a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

If I have a pointer to an object and I want to get a pointer to an object that is say 16 bytes after the pointer how do I add the 16 byte offset to the pointer?

Also, memory addresses in 32bit systems look like this 0x00000000. If I change an address like 0x00000001 to 0x00000002 how many bytes are skipped?

Comment: If the object is 16 bytes, simply increment the pointer, or index the pointer (`pSomeObject[1]`).  If 16 bytes is arbitrary, then [Kerrek's answer has you covered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211923/adding-an-offest-to-a-pointer/7211937#7211937).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pointers count bytes, so to point at the next byte you would need to change a pointer's value by 1. Pointer arithmetic, however, counts the objects pointed to by the pointer, and incrementing a pointer increases its value by the size of its pointee type. If you want to point at bytes, use a `char` pointer, since `char` has size 1 by definition, and pointer arithmetic on `char` pointers is lets you point at bytes:

```
T * p  = get_pointer();

char * cp = reinterpret_cast<char*>(p);

cp += 16;
```

Casting pointers to and from char types does not constitute type punning and is explicitly allowed by the standard. However, you must not use the resulting pointer to access any objects that aren't actually at that address.

Comment: ohh, beat me by 40 seconds. :)

Comment: I think what you meant is that pointers count objects; incrementing a pointer by 1 makes it point to the next object of whatever type it points to.  You clearly knew that, but your first sentence could be interpreted to mean that incrementing a pointer of any type advances to the next byte.

Comment: @Keith: You're talking about pointer *arithmetic*. I was referring to the actual pointer *values*. Arithmetic advances the value of a typed pointer by the size of the type.

Comment: @Brian: Type punning is when you refer to a variable of one type through a pointer to another type, like `float a; int b = *(int*)(&a);`. That's undefined behaviour, unless one of the types is a char. Practically, though, type punning will "break strict aliasing rules", which interfere with the strict aliasing optimisations.

Comment: Kerrek, yes, he was clearly talking about "pointer arithmetic", but then you also used the exact words "an increment by 1 moves the pointer to point [...]". The correct, unambiguous way to word that would be "a value of 1 higher indicates that the pointer will point [...]".

Comment: @KeithThompson: I reworded this a bit. It wasn't a great answer to begin with, I hope it's a bit better now.

Comment: Hmm. I'm still (4 years later!) not crazy about that first sentence. The only reasonable interpretation of "chang[ing] a pointer's value by 1" is adding 1 to it -- which causes it to point to the next *object*, not the next byte. `char*` pointers count bytes (because the objects they point to are 1 byte in size).

Comment: @KeithThompson: Yeah, it's a mess. Pointers have no intrinsic numeric interpretation. The mapping to ints is unspecified. Maybe I just delete the whole thing. I think an explanation via uintptr_t's could be contrived, but actually I think even the Standard itself is confused here and never outright admits that objects are arrays of characters (it says "sequence of characters", which is not a normative term and does not even permit pointer arithmetic).

Answer (score 2):

> If I have a pointer to an object and I want to get a pointer to an object that is say 16 bytes after the pointer how do I add the 16 byte offset to the pointer?

Casting through `char*` will work, but this may be considered bad practice depending on the details of your scenario:

```
T *ptr = initialize_ptr(); // Do whatever initialization you need to.

ptr = (T*)(((char*)ptr) + 16);
```

> Also, memory addresses in 32bit systems look like this 0x00000000. If I change an address like 0x00000001 to 0x00000002 how many bytes are skipped?

The difference between 2 and 1 is 1 -- exactly one byte would be skipped.

Answer (score 1):

You would do this :

```
char *arr = (char*)((void*) ptrToSomeObject);
&arr[15]
```

Whats happening under the hood

1. Any ptr can be converted to 'void*'
2. 'void *' can be converted to any type of ptr.
3. arr[15]  ==    (arr+15bytes)

Comment: `(char*)ptrToSomeObject` should be sufficient.

Comment: Yeah, thinking of it, yes. :)